# Can I add an actor to the back layer in Libgdx?

Tags: android, game-engine, libgdx, layer, actor

I am making a game in Libgdx and I have a little problem. I have a number of actors that show up on the screen dynamically. If there is an Image actor that shows up after the first, could I send it to the back so that it doesn't cover the first one that is already on the screen?

Usually Libgdx adds each new actor higher in hierarchy like a stack and brings every one to the front.

Answer (score 10):

Try the following methods in the Actor class: [toFront()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#toFront%28%29), [toBack()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#toBack%28%29) & [setZIndex()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setZIndex%28int%29)

Comment: I sorted it out preliminary with the Actor Group widget, there you can set the addActorAt([index_number])